# $\int_0^t \frac{\sin x}{x}dx=\frac{1}{2i}\int_{-1}^1\frac{e^{iwt}}{w}dw$?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, complex-analysis, fourier-analysis

How the following identity is proved? $$\int_0^t \frac{\sin x}{x}dx=\frac{1}{2i}\int_{-1}^1\frac{e^{iwt}}{w}dw$$

Answer (score 1):

Start with the RHS: $$\frac{1}{2i} \int_{-1}^1 \frac{e^{iwt}}{w} dw \\ = \frac{1}{2i} \int_{-1}^1 \frac{\cos(wt)}{w} dw+\frac 12 \int_{-1}^1 \frac{\sin(wt)}{w} dw$$ The first integral evaluates to zero, as the integrand is odd. Substituting $wt=x \implies tdw=dx$ in the second gives $$\frac 12 \int_{-t}^t \frac{\sin x}{x}dx=\frac 12 \cdot 2\int_0^t \frac{\sin x}{x} dx$$

where the last step follows from the ‘even-ness’ of $\frac{\sin x}{x}$.

Answer (score 0):

$$I=\int_{0}^{1} \frac{\sin x}{x} dx= \int_{0}^{1}\frac{e^{ix}-e^{-ix}}{2ix}dx=\int_{0}^{1}\frac{e^{ix}}{2ix}dx-\int_{0}^{1}\frac{e^{-ix}}{2ix} dx.$$
In the second integral let $x=-y \implies dx=-dy$, them
$$I=\int_{0}^{1}\frac{e^{ix}}{2ix}dx+\int_{-1}^{0}\frac{e^{iy}}{2iy} dx =\int_{-1}^{1}\frac{e^{2iw}}{2iw} dw.$$
Lstly we have have put $x=w=y$.

Answer (score 0):

Just another way to see it.
$$
\begin{aligned}
&\int_{0}^t \frac{\sin x}{x}dx\\
=&\frac{1}{2i}\int_{0}^t \frac{e^{i x}-e^{-ix}}{x} dx\qquad tw=x\\
=&\frac{1}{2i}\int_{0}^1 \frac{e^{itw}-e^{-itw}}{w} dw\\
=&\frac{1}{2i}(\int_{0}^1 \frac{e^{itw}}{w} dw-\int_{0}^1 \frac{e^{-itw}}{w} dw)\\
=&\frac{1}{2i}\int_{-1}^1 \frac{e^{itw}}{w} dw,
\end{aligned}
$$
where
$$\begin{aligned}
&-\int_{0}^1 \frac{e^{-itw}}{w} dw\quad -u=w\\
=&-\int_{0}^{-1} \frac{e^{itu}}{u} du\\
=&\int_{-1}^0 \frac{e^{itw}}{w} dw
\end{aligned}$$